# .Text property of TextBox with CalendarExtender is always empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

It's been a long time since I've worked on asp.net web forms, and I need a little refresher.  I'm doing some mods to an old app...

```
<asp:TextBox 
    ID="Text_DatePerformed" 
    runat="server" 
    CssClass="style_default" 
    Font-Size="8pt" 
    Width="75px" 
    ReadOnly="true">
</asp:TextBox>

<asp:CalendarExtender 
    ID="CalendarExtender2" 
    TargetControlID="Text_DatePerformed" 
    Format="MM/dd/yyyy" 
    runat="server" />
```

This appears to be working in the UI.  If I click in the textbox the date-picker pops up, I can pick a date, and the correct date appears in the textbox. But, trouble I'm having is, in the code-behind, the `.Text` attribute always comes up empty.

```
string DatePerformed = Text_DatePerformed.Text;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `readonly=false` otherwise ViewState doesn't persist it.

```
<asp:TextBox 
    ID="Text_DatePerformed" 
    runat="server" 
    CssClass="style_default" 
    Font-Size="8pt" 
    Width="75px" 
    ReadOnly="false">
</asp:TextBox>
```

If you need it you either have to make it readonly at clientside or set it  on `Page_Load` or later:

```
 Text_DatePerformed.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
```